# What disc is being referred to in Holling’s disc equation?

Tags: reference-request

The question says it all. I’ve google-searched, but can find any explanation offered for why Holling’s disc equation is called a ‘disc’ equation.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_response

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quoting from http://www.tiem.utk.edu/~gross/bioed/bealsmodules/holling.html:

“Holling's disk equation, named after experiments he performed in which a blindfolded assistant picked up sandpaper disks from a table, describes the type II functional response.”

Holling's original article about this from 1959 is officially [here](https://www.cambridge.org/core/journals/canadian-entomologist/article/some-characteristics-of-simple-types-of-predation-and-parasitism1/9E1E7D2CCC314766A424680444F4EA9F), behind a paywall, but Google also found [another pdf](http://cmore.soest.hawaii.edu/summercourse/2010/documents/Holling_1959b.pdf).

Comment: Bingo. Thanks. Hmmm, the system says I have one more character to go. Okay, here goes: Hip hip hooray for Esperanto!